# Find programmatically all classes, grammars, and roles in a Raku package

Tags: oop, raku, introspection

How can I find programmatically all the classes, grammars, and roles in a Raku package? (Specified with a string.)

I examined discussions/posts similar to the ones linked below, but the code I came up with is very hard to use. (And does not do the job.)

- [Meta-programming: what, why and how](https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2011/12/14/meta-programming-what-why-and-how/) (perl6advent)
- [Day 19 – Introspection](https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2015/12/19/day-19-introspection/) (perl6advent)
- [How do I access a module's symbol table dynamically at runtime in Raku?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67040798) (stackoverflow)
- [Is there a way to get a list of all known types in a Perl 6 program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44861432) (stackoverflow)

### Motivation

I would like to automatically generate UML class diagrams for Raku packages.

See the
[PlantUML](https://plantuml.com)
[diagrams](https://github.com/antononcube/Raku-ML-StreamsBlendingRecommender/tree/main/explanations)
for the Raku package:
[ML::StreamsBlendingRecommender](https://github.com/antononcube/Raku-ML-StreamsBlendingRecommender).

[image]

I considered the steps:

- Design parser(s) of the code of classes in software packages made with languages like C++, Java, Kotlin, Raku
- Generate the corresponding PlantUML code over the parsing results

(Such parsers might not be that hard to derive. Probably, the work of [DrForr](https://github.com/drforr) provides good starts.)

But given Raku's introspection abilities, instead of parsing Raku code I should be able to "just" traverse package namespaces and classes. (Instead of making a parser.)

Comment: Quoting from ++@smls's "get a list of all known types" answer you provided: "If you wanted only classes, you could add the following step: `.grep({ .value.HOW.^name eq 'Perl6::Metamodel::ClassHOW' })`". I think it would be helpful if you elaborated on why you've concluded that using that kind of approach won't suffice.

Comment: @raith I provided motivation.

Comment: @raiph I studied somewhat deeper the code in your comment. I mostly figured out how to answer my question (and generate UML diagrams.) Please, see the package [UML::Translators](https://github.com/antononcube/Raku-UML-Translators).

Comment: Nice! :) Would I be right in thinking `TraverseNameSpace` could be broken out into its own package and added to the ecosystem to become a universal function for this purpose? And then perhaps posted as an accepted answer for this SO?

Comment: @raith Yes! I was thinking to post the code of `TraverseNameSpace` and / or to give the function `get-namespace-classes` of `UML::Translators` as an answer.

Comment: I encourage you to do so. :) Btw, and just so you know, the nick you're writing isn't my SO nick, which is instead @raiph, with a p, not a t. It's just a nick, not my name, so please rest assured I really didn't/don't mind you using raith. It was a sweet reminder of my childhood love of [a Scottish soccer club](https://www.raithrovers.net/) But SO doesn't know that!

Comment: @raiph Dully noted!

Answer (score 6):

There is no "central" dictionary of classes in Raku.  And making the question even harder to solve, classes only now about their parent classes and roles they consume.  But they do **not** know about any classes that inherit from them.  Or if you look at a role, which other roles and classes consume that role.

Classes and roles in Raku are therefore irresponsible parents :-)

I guess there could be a way to do some trickery in the MOP, but that could have significant performance effects and cause memory leaks (as many temporary classes wouldn't be garbage collected anymore, because the record keeping would keep it alive).

Answer (score 0):

The question :

> How can I find programmatically all the classes, grammars, and roles in a Raku package? (Specified with a string.)

is answered with the package [`UML::Translators`](https://raku.land/zef:antononcube/UML::Translators).

For example,

```
.say for get-namespace-classes( 'ML::TriesWithFrequencies' ).map({ $_ ~~ Str ?? $_ !! $_.^name }).sort

# ML::TriesWithFrequencies::LeafProbabilitiesGatherer
# ML::TriesWithFrequencies::ParetoBasedRemover
# ML::TriesWithFrequencies::PathsGatherer
# ML::TriesWithFrequencies::RegexBasedRemover
# ML::TriesWithFrequencies::ThresholdBasedRemover
# ML::TriesWithFrequencies::Trie
# ML::TriesWithFrequencies::TrieTraverse
# ML::TriesWithFrequencies::Trieish
# TRIEROOT
# TRIEVALUE
```

---

The package provides the Command Line Interface (CLI) script `to-uml-spec` that can be used to generate UML specs with the
[PlantUML](https://plantuml.com)
domain specific language. Here is an example:

```bash
to-uml-spec --/methods --/attributes 'Chemistry::Stoichiometry'
```

```
@startuml
class Chemistry::Stoichiometry::Grammar <<grammar>> {
}
Chemistry::Stoichiometry::Grammar --|> Grammar
Chemistry::Stoichiometry::Grammar --|> Match
Chemistry::Stoichiometry::Grammar --|> Capture
Chemistry::Stoichiometry::Grammar --|> Chemistry::Stoichiometry::Grammar::ChemicalElement
Chemistry::Stoichiometry::Grammar --|> Chemistry::Stoichiometry::Grammar::ChemicalEquation
Chemistry::Stoichiometry::Grammar --|> NQPMatchRole


class Chemistry::Stoichiometry::ResourceAccess  {
}


class Chemistry::Stoichiometry::Actions::MolecularMass  {
}


class Chemistry::Stoichiometry::Actions::EquationMatrix  {
}


class Chemistry::Stoichiometry::Actions::EquationBalance  {
}
Chemistry::Stoichiometry::Actions::EquationBalance --|> Chemistry::Stoichiometry::Actions::EquationMatrix


class Chemistry::Stoichiometry::Actions::WL::System  {
}


@enduml
```

Using CLI and a PlantUML JAR file we can generate UML diagrams like this:

```
to-uml-spec --/methods --/attributes 'Chemistry::Stoichiometry' | java -jar ~/Downloads/plantuml-1.2022.5.jar -pipe -tjpg > /tmp/myuml.jpg
```

[image]